# To add hyphen in URL in mod rewrite

Tags: .htaccess

I am curious why it cannot work and looking for a solution.

the following is in my htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^field/category/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)&([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)$ field.php?cat[]=$1&cat[]=$2
```

This works well and the url will be domain.com/field/category/Ball&Drinks

How can I change the & to - and make it become domain.com/field/category/Ball-Drinks

I try

```
RewriteRule ^field/category/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)$ field.php?cat[]=$1&cat[]=$2
```

and it doesn't work. The - character is not taken as a literal. Anyone can help? Thanks.

Comment: What about your previous question, don't need an answer any more?

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the - character:

```
RewriteRule ^field/category/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)\-([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)$ field.php?cat[]=$1&cat[]=$2
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I just spent an hour figuring this out so I figured I should share the answer:

Replace the hyphen with `[\-]` to get the RewriteRule to treat it as a string literal.

So final code would be: `^field/category/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)[\-]([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)$ field.php?cat[]=$1&cat[]=$2`

Comment: If you do it that way, I think you’d need to change the `$2` to `$3`, because your change causes the `$2` backreference to become `-` right? (instead of what’s in `([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)`). But anyway I think this answer could avoid that problem altogether by just using `[\-]` instead of `(\-)`.